# Keyboard language changes on its own

Tags: keyboard-layout

On windows 10 I use 2 languages, English with UK keyboard (Shift 2 is ") and Greek (Shift 2 is @). When Ι am using the UK keyboard for English and press the @ key (next to the Enter key) it switches the language to Greek as if I pressed Alt-Shift. If I remove the Greek language the @ key only works if I long press it.

I have checked sticky keys and all the settings there. This only happens under my Windows account. When I created a temp local account it was fine. It also works on the logon screen when I type my password.

Comment: I've had this happen due to certain games - which could be a factor. IIRC cyberpunk 2077 does this

Answer (score 1):

Since everything was OK in the test account, I searched the registry for the keyboard layouts there and copied them over to my account. That fixed the problem. The keys I copied were:

- [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout]
- [HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout]